# How to limit mod_proxy_connect's host?

Tags: apache, ssh, mod-proxy, tunnel

I wanna tunnel my ssh though port 80(listened by apache). mod_proxy & mod_proxy_connect provide me with **AllowCONNECT** directive, allowing me to use **CONNECT** `host:22 HTTP/1.1` to connect to my ssh host. But the host following **CONNECT** is not limited, is there a solution?

Comment: And what about `<ProxyMatch>` directive in apache.conf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself. Just to add a few lines in the

apache2.2/modules/proxy/mod_proxy_connect.c +123

```
char *allowed_hosts[] = { 
    "your host",
    "127.0.0.1",
    "localhost"
};  
int hosts_num = sizeof(allowed_hosts) / sizeof(allowed_hosts[0]);
int k;
for (k = 0; k < hosts_num; k++) {
    if (strncmp(uri.hostname, allowed_hosts[k], strlen(allowed_hosts[k])) == 0) {
        break;
    }
}
if (k == hosts_num) {
    return ap_proxyerror(r, HTTP_BAD_GATEWAY,
                         apr_pstrcat(p, "host not allowed for: ",
                                     uri.hostname, NULL));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution that does not require changing Apache source code. Put the following in your httpd.conf file:

```
   # By default, deny everyone. If you don't,
   # others will be able to connect to port 22 on any host.
   <Proxy *>
       Order deny,allow
       Deny from all
   </Proxy>

  # Only allow CONNECT to specific hosts;
  <ProxyMatch (^(host1\.com|host2|host3):22$)>
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
  </ProxyMatch>
```

Changing Apache source code creates a maintenance burden, since you'll have to reapply your patch to every new Apache version.

Comment: Thanks a lot! While as sooooooooo many years have passed, I've completely given up apache and switched to nginx :)

Comment: This does not actually work. Proxy/ProxyMatch don't match against where the connect tunnel is going, they match agains the proxy "worker" being used which is literally * for fwd proxy.